# XSLT: to match the field string if result is true then copy the complete corresponding node

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am fairly new in XSLT.

I need assistance and guidance to do the following task

I have one input xml:

```
<Prices>
<Price>
    <Name>1234</Name>
    <Type>account</Type>
    <group>shell</group>
    <Cost>0.23</Cost>

</Price>
<Price>
    <Name>1234</Name>
    <Type>account</Type>
    <group>shell</group>
    <Cost>0.23</Cost>

</Price>
<Price>
    <Name>test12345</Name>
    <Type>Data Stored - Tables</Type>
    <group>--</group>
    <Cost>0.00</Cost>

</Price>
```

I need to search for group in each of the element like in this case it is **shell**. 
Once the shell is matched the complete nodes should be present in the output xml like

```
<Prices>
<Price>
    <Name>1234</Name>
    <Type>account</Type>
    <group>shell</group>
    <Cost>0.23</Cost>

</Price>
<Price>
    <Name>1234</Name>
    <Type>account</Type>
    <group>shell</group>
    <Cost>0.23</Cost>

</Price>
 </Prices>
```

I have tried using lot of xslt but I am not able to get this output.

Can some one please help me.

Here, the input file has only 3 nodes but actually it can have more than 50nodes as well.

Tried using this xslt but its failing

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<!-- Identity transform -->
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()"> 
<xsl:copy> 
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:param name="str" select="'shell'"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<output> 
<xsl:for-each select="//*[.=$str]">
<xsl:copy> 
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:for-each> 
</output> 
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks Martin in helping previous use case.

Also now I want this to be like including search for two or more variables. To understand, below is the xml input file

```
<Prices>

<Price>
<Name>1234</Name>
<Type>account</Type>
<group>shell</group>
<Cost>0.23</Cost>

</Price>

<Price>
<Name>1234</Name>
<Type>account</Type>
<group>shell</group>
<Cost>0.23</Cost>

</Price>

<Price>
<Name>test12345</Name>
<Type>Data Stored - Tables</Type>
<group>--</group>
<Cost>0.00</Cost>
</Price>

<Price>
<Name>1234</Name>
<Type>account</Type>
<group>shell12345</group>
<Cost>0.54</Cost>
</Price>

<Price>
<Name>1234</Name>
<Type>account</Type>
<group>nutshell1234</group>
<Cost>0.60</Cost>
</Price>

</Prices>
```

I want the output to be

```
<Prices>

<Price>
<Name>1234</Name>
<Type>account</Type>
<group>shell</group>
<Cost>0.23</Cost>

</Price>

<Price>
<Name>1234</Name>
<Type>account</Type>
<group>shell</group>
<Cost>0.23</Cost>

</Price>
<Price>
<Name>1234</Name>
<Type>account</Type>
<group>shell12345</group>
<Cost>0.54</Cost>
</Price>

<Price>
<Name>1234</Name>
<Type>account</Type>
<group>nutshell1234</group>
<Cost>0.60</Cost>
</Price>

</Prices>
```

Also, the groups which has sheel, nutshell, shell12345 could be something different also without matching any strings as well.
But the good point is what I have to search is there available so if needed we can just provide the hardcoded value as well.

Comment: Try any basic XPath and XSLT tutorial and you will for sure find a way to select those elements. Or at least show us one of the attempts you have tried and explain in what way it fails and why you don't find ways to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am trying using this

Comment: <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
         </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

<xsl:param name="str" select="'shell'"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <output>
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[.=$str]">
    <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>   
      </xsl:for-each>  
      
    </output>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Please edit your question and provide any code there as a well-formatted code snippet.

Comment: Can you confirm exactly what XSLT version you can use, and tag the question accordingly? If you are only able to use XSLT 1.0 then Martin's answer won't be valid as it is considered an error to use a variable in a template match (although some processors do allow it). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you start with the identity transformation template I think the simplest approach is to add an empty template for those `Price` elements not having the desired `group` value:

```
 <xsl:template match="Price[not(group = $str)]"/>
```

as that way these will not be copied.

Online in an XSLT 3 version at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtri and an XSLT 2 version at http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/eiZQaET.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I am not able to open XSLT 2 version link.

Comment: If the input xml has two groups which needs to be selected in output xml then how to include the if statements

Comment: @2437850 Please edit your question and show us what the parameter would look like with 2 values.

Comment: Hi Michael
I edited the question and included the other case

Comment: That's not two groups; that's still one group. Simply change the predicate to `[not(contains(group, $str))]`.

Comment: I didnot get that. Can you explain

Comment: if I am declaring another global variable like str1 with select as shell12345 then the output is coming as blank

Comment: @2437850 You keep changing the requirements and I have lost track.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185757/discussion-between-2437850-and-michael-hor257k).